# Spherical Aberrations from Concave Mirrors

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

I am trying to derive a general equation for a ray reflected from a concave mirror like so:
[image]

I've started with a generic ray with the equation $y = h$ and a circle centered on the origin $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$. I thought I could solve the problem using simple coordinate geometry but I got stuck when I realised I only have the point ($\sqrt {a^2-h^2},h$) from which to construct the line equation and no other way to get the slope that I could see. So I'm wondering is there another way to go about this or am I missing something from my technique?

Comment: Isolate y and differentiate to get the slope

Comment: It's not clear what "the problem" is. Let P be the point $(\sqrt {a^2-h^2},h$). The mirror is a circle, so the tangent at P is perpendicular to the normal OP.